# Testing InfiniteScroll component from react-infinite-scroller

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-infinite-scroller` to make several calls to a paginated endpoint.

I haven't found any way to test the function that is triggered when a new request has to be done to the server.
I've taken a look at the [github repository](https://github.com/danbovey/react-infinite-scroller), but there is no information about how to trigger the function `loadMore` from a test.

The actual code looks like this:

```
<PaginatedList
  data-testid="paginated-list-testid"
>
 <InfiniteScroll
     pageStart={0}
     loadMore={this._nextPage}
     hasMore={hasMore}
     loader={<div key={0}>Loading...</div>}
     useWindow={false}
 >
  {this._renderElements()}
 </InfiniteScroll>
</PaginatedList>
```

The `_nextPage` function looks like follow:

```
async _nextPage() {
        const { hasMore} = this.state;
        const { externalCondition } = this.props;
        if (hasMore) {
            const response = externalCondition ? await this.repositoryA.next() : await this.repositoryB.next();
            const nextElements = response.elements;
            this.setState({
                elements: nextElements,
                loading: false,
                hasMore: response.hasNext,
            });
        }
    }
```

I wanna test that given an `externalCondition` the function `this.repositoryA.next()` is called. However, my test does not even reach this method.

This is my test:

```
test('Should\'ve called the repositoryA.next()', async () => {
    const sampleUserId = 1;
    const paginatedListTestId = "paginated-list-testid";
    const renderComponent = render(
        <PaginatedList
            userId={sampleUserId}
        />,
    );
    const { getByTestId } = renderComponent;
    fireEvent.scroll(getByTestId(paginatedListTestId), { target: { scrollY: 9000 } });
});
```

I know that my test does not have an assert yet, but I was debugging and I wasn't able to reach my function.
Neither scrolling to 9000 nor -9000.
Any help is welcome.
(The code has been a little bit changed due to privacy, so please, obviate any typo or mismatching variable names)

Comment: what's your condition for the hasMore prop? The loadMore function will trigger when you scroll to the end of the page only when the hasMore prop is true. Can you post your hasMore prop logic?

Comment: The `hasMore` value is retrieved from the state.
During the `componentDidMount` there is a call to the repository whose response contains if there is more pages left or not.

The logic is pretty similar to the `_nextPage` function.
`componentDidMount() {`
`const response = await this._fetchRecords();`
`this.setState({ elements: response.elements, loading: false, hasMore: response.hasNext })`
`}`

This call is done correctly, and the `response.hasNext` value is `True`.

Comment: Did you figure this out? For me, the `loadMore` is called, I've set the state correctly, the items length is 20 (previously was 10), yet the UI won't get updated somehow even with `waitForTimeout`